# Caching in JAVA

Tags: java, memcached

Is there a way to use memcahce in java ?

or

Does java have equal or better caching method like memcache ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you not look at the [memcached website](http://code.google.com/p/memcached/wiki/Clients#Java)?  It says right there how to use it in Java.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe in your usage scenario an in-memory cache is sufficent. There are a lot caching solutions for Java, like JCS, EHCache, [cache2k](http://cache2k.org), OSCache.

See also [memcache vs java memory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5465737/memcache-vs-java-memory) for a discussion when to use memcache are a Java only approach.