# Memcache vs Java Memory

Tags: caching, memory, memcached, redis

Simple, probably dumb question: Suppose I have a Java server that stores in memory commonly used keys and values which I can query (let's say in a HashMap)

What's the difference between that and using Memcache (or even Redis)? They both store things in memory. Is there a benefit to one or the other? Does Memcache leaves less of a memory footprint? Can store more in less memory? Faster to query? No difference?

Answer (score 57, accepted):

Advantages of Java memory over memcache:

1. Java memory is faster (no network).
2. Java memory won't require serialization, you have Java objects available to you.

Advantages of memcache over Java memory:

1. It can be accessed by more than one application server, so your cache will be shared among all your app servers.
2. It can be accessed by a variety of different servers, so long as they all agree on the key scheme and the serialization.
3. It will discard expired cache values, so you get time-based invalidation.

Comment: Also using lots of Java Memory makes the garbage colector take longer, so there is a limit to the say you can have a java process even if you have the RAM.   memcache does not have a garbage collector that gets slower with more live data items.

Comment: One could implement time-based invalidation in a Java memory implementation, so I wouldn't consider it an advantage of memcached over Java memory; it's more of an advantage of memcached over specific in-memory implementations.

Comment: @MaxNanasy Yes you can always implement something like LRU cache that works with Java memory.

Answer (score 32):

I just made a benchmark between a concurrent hash map, memcached, and MySQL.

[image: HashMap vs. memcached vs. MySQL]

Here are the results:

Type    Insert  Lookup  Remove

ConcurrentHashMap   264ms   93ms    82ms

Memcached   6549ms  5976ms  4900ms

Mysql   55754ms 26002ms 57899ms

A thread pool was used for this benchmark.

Some more information can be found here:
http://www.incentergy.de/2013/12/big-data-architecture-patterns-for-performance/

Further the following cache might be an alternative to memcached:
https://code.google.com/p/kitty-cache/

Comment: Because somebody ask me here is a repository with the code: https://github.com/ManuelB/key-value-benchmark

Answer (score 16):

It depends on what you're wanting. An in-memory map will be faster; data expiry isn't really an issue (see: Google Guava's [MapMaker](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/tags/release08/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/MapMaker.html), which can create a map that expires entries after reads and/or writes, and let's not forget things like [OSCache](http://www.opensymphony.com/oscache/) and [EHCache](http://ehcache.org/), not to mention distributed things like [GigaSpaces XAP](http://gigaspaces.com/) or [Coherence](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/middleware/coherence/overview/index.html)).

The caching projects (XAP, OSCache, EhCache, Coherence, etc) can distribute cache entries, so you get natural sharding and other facilities; Coherence can manage transactions and write-through, and XAP is actually designed to serve as a system of record (where writing to it gets synchronized and replicated, such that you are using an in-memory data grid as your actual data storage mechanism rather than using a database.)

Memcached is... well, you can access a memcached server instance from a series of machines. Memcached as an API is simply a key/value store, and distribution is *entirely* accomplished on the client side. It's certainly got the basics, I guess, and it's definitely got multiple language APIs, but it's really pretty limp otherwise.

(BTW, GigaSpaces has a Memcached layer, so you *could* theoretically use memcached as a system of record...)

Comment: What I basically want is a key-value map in memory that will expire keys as well as remove keys if the memory is low. I'm planning to manipulate this map using Java. Memcached sounds perfect for that purpose. The problem is I want to create a JAR, which I'm planning to distribute to other clients. Other people may not have memcached, or may not want to install memcached. So I want the capabilities of memcached w/o the need to install anything else. A Java version of memcached is what I'm after.

Comment: Sounds like you want a simple cache, not memcached - memcached is an API for connecting to an *external* server, so if you're talking about in-memory, memcached isn't your target.

Comment: Sorry for double comment - edit didn't work. What I would do, honestly, is create a custom cache, with a background thread that monitors system resources. If resources are low, expire the oldest entries; also, expire entries if they're past their expiry time. It would be pretty easy to do, and would have the benefit of meeting your requirements exactly.

Comment: Thanks. But that sounds like non-trivial work. That was why I was attracted to memcached =) I did some research and found out about QuickCached, which looks like an implementation of memcached.

Comment: **nod** fair enough. I'd think it'd take maybe ten minutes of heads-down coding to write a map like that, but that's probably more time than using a pre-written product would take.

Comment: @Hisoka: Google Guava's MapMaker provides soft keys (will be removed if memory is low) and time-based expiration, super easily.

Comment: I dont need such a thing anymore hehe.. that idea was scratched ^_^